# How to listen to internet audio streams

Tags: audio, streaming

I connected my RPi onto my stereo so I can listen to my music.

However, I want to listen to a few internet-radio-streams. The streams are available in ASX, MP3 and some of them through SHOUTCAST.

I've already installed MPD and ICECAST and they are working correctly. How can I listen to these audio streams ?

Answer (score 6):

You need a client that can connect to MPD and tell it what to play.

The simplest is the command line client mpc that can run on the Raspberry Pi. After installing it, you would do something like:

```
$ mpc add http://62.204.145.218:8000/radio1rock64
$ mpc play
```

The URL to add will of course be different - it will be the address you set up in Icecast for your stream.

There are many other MPD clients available, for example MPDroid that runs on Android phones, and can connect over a local Wifi network.

Comment: I tried it but I get the following error: error: Timeout

Comment: Make sure can access the internet via the Pi.

Comment: It is conected to internet and I even tried it with another URL-stream and they all results in an timeout error

Comment: Like @Munkeh suggested try to check if your internet connection is up and running (e.g. ping www.google.pl).

Comment: Wow I don't no why but I tried again and now it's working fine. This stream shout://www.kickradio.nl:9000 don't work get the following error: error: unsupported URI scheme

I replaced shout with http but that don't work either. Is a shout-stream not working in MPD?

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to listen internet radio streams.

- MPD : Music Player Daemon,
  mpc add http://rdshout.turkuvazgroup.net:7000
  mpc play
- Mplayer
  mplayer http://rdshout.turkuvazgroup.net:7000
- PyRadio (https://github.com/coderholic/pyradio)
  After build the python program;

mkdir ~/.pyradio
echo "Romantik Radyo, http://rdshout.turkuvazgroup.net:7000/listen.pls" >> stations.csv
pyradio

Answer (score 0):

MPD can play streams.   I've found that you can add them to your library by creating playlists.  Create a text file with an `.m3u` extension in your MPD music library with a different stream on each line.  Or create a separate playlist file for each station.   For example `/usr/lib/mpd/library/rock-1-radio.m3u` could have the content:

```
http://62.204.145.218:8000/radio1rock64
```

Once you rebuild your mpd database (`mpc update`) then that radio station will appear in your library list for all clients.